# Headphone sockets on Virgin Atlantic Upper Class

Tags: gear, in-flight-services, virgin-atlantic

I'm flying from London Gatwick (LGW) to Montego Bay, Jamaica (MBJ) in September with Virgin Atlantic (Upper Class, if this makes a difference). I'm taking my own headphones.

Are the sockets one pin or do I need to take an adapter?

Comment: You shouldn't need an adapter, but the adapters are so small, I see little downside in bringing one with you just in case you need it.

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://www.virgin-atlantic.com/gb/en/travel-information/baggage/hand-baggage.html)

> Headphones for onboard use (they’ll need the standard 3.5mm jack).